# Converting orientation and speed to position

Tags: orientation, euler-angles, cartesian-coordinates

I have a body located at `(x,y,z)` at time `t0`. I know the body is moving at a constant speed, `s`. The body's orientation is `(h,p,r)` (heading pitch and roll). I would like to calculate the location of the body after `t` seconds as a function of `x,y,z,h,p,r`. How do I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. You know the starting location, and could poll the orientation of the body. Then you move with a constant speed (s is a vector or just the magnitude?) then (x,y,z,t1)==(x,y,z,t0) + s * t, and (h,p,r,t0)==(h,p,r,t1)

Comment: s is speed, the magnitude of the velocity vector. I am trying to calculate the velocity vector v, from the heading, pitch and roll.

Comment: The (h,p,r) is given in t1?

Comment: the h,p,r is constant